# PHP variable doesn't load with MySQL update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have omitted unnecessary code. Whenever I try to run this, it processes without any errors. However, in the update query, whenever I use WHERE student_id='$student_id', it doesn't update. No errors, it just doesn't update. However, when I use the numeric equivalent of the variable, such as 1, it works just fine. What am I missing? Thank you!

```
$resolved_student_id = $_GET['student_id'];

try {
   $request_sd = $db -> prepare("SELECT student_name,tutor,intervention FROM students WHERE student_id='$resolved_student_id'");
   $request_sd -> execute();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
   echo "Could not query database.";
   exit;
}

$studentdata = $request_sd -> fetch();


if ( empty( $_POST ) === false ) {
   if ( empty( $_POST['student_name'] ) === true || empty( $_POST['student_tutor'] ) === true || empty( $_POST['student_intervention'] ) === true ) {
    $updateStudentInformation = "You need to fill out all fields.";
} else {
    $student_name = $_POST['student_name'];
    $student_tutor = $_POST['student_tutor'];
    $student_intervention = $_POST['student_intervention'];

    try {
       $updatedata = $db -> prepare("UPDATE students SET student_name='$student_name', tutor='$student_tutor', intervention='$student_intervention' WHERE student_id='$resolved_student_id'");
       $updatedata -> execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo "Could not update database.";
       exit;
    }
    header("location: edit.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this in [tag:pdo]?

Comment: Indeed, it is in PDO.

Comment: If you're preparing, please use parameters instead of unescaped strings. Also, have you configured your (PDO?) database to throw exceptions?

Comment: Also `$resolved_student_id` != `$student_id`, could that be a cause?

Comment: I have changed all prepare statements to query statements, and I have configured it to throw exceptions. However, it still doesn't update.

Comment: @user2672698 No, don't do that. Stick with prepared statements but use parameter binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come you are using both get and post methods here?

I guess this: `$resolved_student_id = $_GET['student_id'];`

Should be replaced by: `$resolved_student_id = $_POST['student_id'];`

and if you need both methods make sure to specify the GET data in the form URL.

```
eg:<form method="POST" action="abc.php?student_id=1">
```

And the reason its not updating where `$student_id` is you have not defined any such variable, not at least what i can see here in the code u posted.

Comment: You helped me realise what I did wrong there, thank you very much. It is working now. I was using my form action request to the same page without including the GET variable it needed to process the form properly.

Answer (score 0):

You've written your query as a straight up query (where all the options are defined) but you're running `prepare`, where your query would look like this

```
UPDATE students SET student_name=?, tutor=?, intervention=? WHERE student_id=?
```

Then you would run [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind your data to the prepared statement and then `execute()`

So either convert your query to a prepared statement query and bind your parameters or change from `prepare` to `query`

Comment: 1) PDO, not MySQLi. 2) Whilst it is certainly *recommended* to use parameter binding, you don't have to in order to use `prepare`

Answer (score 0):

Several things here...

1. Configure PDO to throw exceptions. I like using this constructor for optimal MySQL usage

   ```
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
   ```
2. Stop catching exceptions and discarding them. This is most important while developing. Once you're confident that your code runs properly, then you can implement a high-level exception handling scheme. Simply remove the `try` controls and `catch` blocks from your code
3. Use parameter binding with your queries instead of string interpolation. This will make your queries much more resilient to SQL injection attacks.

   ```
   $request_sd = $db->prepare("SELECT student_name,tutor,intervention FROM students WHERE student_id = ?");
   $request_sd->execute([$resolved_student_id]);
   // use array($resolved_student_id) if using an older version of PHP
   ```

   You would do the same with your update query.